# Safari ignoring html5 video muted attribute

Tags: windows, html, safari, html5-video

Not sure what im doing wrong but i cannot get safari to mute my video even though it's defined. it works in other browsers but not safari. Does it support this attribute?? I'd rather not use the javascript/jquery fix but if i have to then i guess. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code

```
    <video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="/media/installation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/media/installation.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="/media/installation.webm" type="video/wbm">
    </video>
```

Comment: Is this still an issue in iOS 9? Is iOS turning in IE (on purpose because they want more people to use apps,..perhaps)? Note: I understand this will be deleted for not being technically helpful, but I enjoyed saying what many of us were thinking : )

Comment: AFAICT, it's still an issue in iOS10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Safari does not support this attribute. It's not listed among the supported attributes in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW2). It's left out of the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Browser_compatibility) table on MDN. Testing shows that setting the `muted` property on the DOM object does not add the attribute. For comparison, setting `controls` to true does set the `controls` attribute.

I'm afraid you need to use Javascript for this.

It's worth noting that Mobile Safari on iOS ignores both `volume` and `muted`, even if you use Javascript. The only way to control volume of a video in that case is with the hardware volume controls.

Comment: thanks, I have a few videos and i guess the best way to move forward is to just rerender my videos without sound, that way i don't have to worry about extra code. i could have sworn it was working at one point in an older version of safari. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It's possible. Wouldn't be the first time Safari removed a feature.

Comment: You can very easily and quickly remove the audio without having to re-compress the video track. `ffmpeg -i input.webm -vcodec copy -an output.webm`

Comment: ffmpeg? i use miro. it doesn't have that option. Do you recommend that program instead? I output my original videos without audio and compressed them a bit more with after effects.

Comment: ffmpeg is a command line program. I believe Miro is built on top of it. It's good for quick stuff like this and/or supporting weird formats.

Comment: ok thanks i remember miro had an ffmpeg setting to do those commands but they removed it for some reason a few upgrades ago.

Thanks for that solution. I'll check it out, though it seemed a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

I have penned down my findings to get autoplaying muted video to work in all ios 10+ safari browsers. This is an amalgam of all hacks there are to get it to work.

If this link works in your troubling ios10+ Safari -> https://ney5u.csb.app/

then follow this thread for answer
https://medium.com/@BoltAssaults/autoplay-muted-html5-video-safari-ios-10-in-react-673ae50ba1f5